# No rollback in hibernate on H2 when temporary tables are involved (multi table bulk queries)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

## Setup

Maven project with Java (17), Hibernate (6.4.1.Final) and H2 database (2.2.224).

There are two (unrelated) entities (`MyFirstEntity` and `MySecondEntity`) and the second entity has a self reference (`@OneToOne` mapping with `@JoinTable`). These entities use three tables:

`MY_FIRST_ENTITY`: `id`, `title` (unique)

`MY_SECOND_ENTITY`: `id`, `title`

`MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING`: `a` (reference to `MY_SECOND_ENTITY`), `b`(reference to `MY_SECOND_ENTITY`)

At the end of this question a Java file, a hibernate properties file and a maven pom file are provided, which can be used to reproduce the issue. And also might help to follow the textual problem description.

## Context

I stumbled about this problem while upgrading a Spring Boot application from version 2 to 3. The example provided here is a very striped down reproducer of what occurred in [`DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) test classes.

## Problem description

Within a transaction an entry of `MyFirstEntity` is persisted with title "a" (there is an unique constraint on this column) and the session is flushed. Afterwards an update statement is executed: `UPDATE MY_SECOND_ENTITY SET title=null` (this should be a no-op, since there are no entries in this table). Then the transaction *rollbacked*.

After that another transaction is created and again an entry of `MyFirstEntity` is persisted with title "a" and this time the transaction is *committed*. Committing leads to an error because the unique constraint is violated:

> Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.CONSTRAINT_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.MY_FIRST_ENTITY(TITLE NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 1 */ 'a' )"

This is surprising to me, since the first transaction is rollbacked.
Hibernate seems to be using temporary tables for optimizing the update statement ([multi-table bulk operation](https://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/)). If the update statement is removed, everything works fine and there is no constraint violation in the second transaction. Also removing the flush call or moving the update statement before the insert statement fixes the constraint violation.

### SQL statements

First transaction:

> Hibernate: insert into MY_FIRST_ENTITY (title,id) values (?,?)
> Hibernate: create local temporary table HT_MY_SECOND_ENTITY(id uuid not null, primary key (id))
> Hibernate: insert into HT_MY_SECOND_ENTITY(id) select mse1_0.id from MY_SECOND_ENTITY mse1_0
> Hibernate: update MY_SECOND_ENTITY set title=null where id in (select temptable_.id from HT_MY_SECOND_ENTITY temptable_)
> Hibernate: delete from HT_MY_SECOND_ENTITY

Second transaction:

> Hibernate: insert into MY_FIRST_ENTITY (title,id) values (?,?)

### Questions

Can anyone explain why the rollback is not working in some circumstances?
Is this expected behavior or can this considered to be a bug?
Any help or hints are appreciated.

## Sample code

```
import java.util.UUID;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;

public class DemoHibernateApplication {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static final String CREATION_TABLE_1 = """
            CREATE TABLE "MY_FIRST_ENTITY" (
                "ID" UUID NOT NULL,
                "TITLE" VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
            );
            """;
    private static final String CREATION_TABLE_2 = """
            CREATE TABLE "MY_SECOND_ENTITY" (
                "ID" UUID NOT NULL,
                "TITLE" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
            );
            """;
    private static final String CREATION_TABLE_3 = """
            CREATE TABLE "MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING" (
                "A" UUID NOT NULL,
                "B" UUID NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY ("A", "B"),
                FOREIGN KEY("A") REFERENCES MY_SECOND_ENTITY("ID"),
                FOREIGN KEY("B") REFERENCES MY_SECOND_ENTITY("ID")
            );
            """;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createTables();
        executeQueries();
    }

    private static void createTables() {
        try (Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.createNativeMutationQuery(CREATION_TABLE_1)
                    .executeUpdate();
            session.createNativeMutationQuery(CREATION_TABLE_2)
                    .executeUpdate();
            session.createNativeMutationQuery(CREATION_TABLE_3)
                    .executeUpdate();

            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    private static void executeQueries() {
        try (Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.persist(newMyFirstEntityWithTitle("a"));
            session.flush();
            session.createMutationQuery("UPDATE MY_SECOND_ENTITY SET title=null")
                    .executeUpdate();

            transaction.rollback();
        }

        try (Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.persist(newMyFirstEntityWithTitle("a"));

            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    private static MyFirstEntity newMyFirstEntityWithTitle(String title) {
        MyFirstEntity myFirstEntity = new MyFirstEntity();
        myFirstEntity.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        myFirstEntity.setTitle(title);
        return myFirstEntity;
    }

    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build();

            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(MyFirstEntity.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(MySecondEntity.class)
                    .buildMetadata()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Entity(name = "MY_FIRST_ENTITY")
    public static class MyFirstEntity {

        @Id
        private UUID id;

        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
        private String title;

        public UUID getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(UUID id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

    }

    @Entity(name = "MY_SECOND_ENTITY")
    public static class MySecondEntity {

        @Id
        private UUID id;

        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
        private String title;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinTable(name = "MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "a") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "b") })
        private MySecondEntity anotherMySecondEntity;

        public UUID getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(UUID id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public MySecondEntity getAnotherMySecondEntity() {
            return anotherMySecondEntity;
        }

        public void setAnotherMySecondEntity(MySecondEntity anotherMySecondEntity) {
            this.anotherMySecondEntity = anotherMySecondEntity;
        }

    }

}
```

#### hibernate.properties

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
hibernate.connection.username=sa
hibernate.connection.password=

hibernate.show_sql=true

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-hibernate</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to H2 executeUpdate function. When the call

```java
session.createMutationQuery("UPDATE MY_SECOND_ENTITY SET title=null")
                    .executeUpdate();
```

happens it goes to [executeUpdate](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcCallableStatement.java#L89) and if you check the documentation line above.

> If auto commit is on, this statement will be committed. If the statement is a DDL statement (create, drop, alter) and does not
> throw an exception, the current transaction (if any) is committed after executing the statement.

Meaning even before your "rollback" the executeUpdate commits the transaction which generates the data inside and after that you get "Unique index or primary key violation"

Here is an example with [postgresql](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/java-examlpes/tree/master/hibernate6) approach. Basically it has hibernate properties with extra config just to test out.

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF
#hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
hibernate.connection.username=postgres
hibernate.connection.password=

hibernate.show_sql=true

#hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

when I ran in my local with postgresql I see the log below.

```
/home/oz-mint/.sdkman/candidates/java/21-graalce/bin/java -javaagent:/home/oz-mint/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/intellij-idea-ultimate/lib/idea_rt.jar=32809:/home/oz-mint/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/intellij-idea-ultimate/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/oz-mint/projects/java-examlpes/hibernate6/target/classes:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.4.1.Final/hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0/jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/2.0.1/jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.5.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/6.0.6.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/jandex/3.1.2/jandex-3.1.2.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.14.7/byte-buddy-1.14.7.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.0/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/4.0.2/jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/4.0.2/jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-activation/2.0.0/angus-activation-2.0.0.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/4.0.2/txw2-4.0.2.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.1.1/istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/jakarta/inject/jakarta.inject-api/2.0.1/jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.13.0/antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/2.2.224/h2-2.2.224.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.7.1/postgresql-42.7.1.jar:/home/oz-mint/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.41.0/checker-qual-3.41.0.jar DemoHibernateApplication
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.username=postgres, logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test, hibernate.show_sql=true, logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG}
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test]
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres}
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: alter table if exists MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING drop constraint if exists FK1c0qvkaoyxgvk8j7lge0f4dvx
Hibernate: alter table if exists MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING drop constraint if exists FKosyih1e60ld4bp8f7hege9xar
Hibernate: drop table if exists MY_FIRST_ENTITY cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists MY_SECOND_ENTITY cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING cascade
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@6e03db1f] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: constraint "fk1c0qvkaoyxgvk8j7lge0f4dvx" of relation "my_second_entity_mapping" does not exist, skipping
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: constraint "fkosyih1e60ld4bp8f7hege9xar" of relation "my_second_entity_mapping" does not exist, skipping
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler logWarning
WARN: drop cascades to 2 other objects
Hibernate: create table MY_FIRST_ENTITY (id uuid not null, title varchar(255) not null unique, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table MY_SECOND_ENTITY (id uuid not null, title varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING (anotherMySecondEntity_id uuid unique, id uuid not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table if exists MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING add constraint FK1c0qvkaoyxgvk8j7lge0f4dvx foreign key (anotherMySecondEntity_id) references MY_SECOND_ENTITY
Jan 13, 2024 12:02:40 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7d97e06c] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: alter table if exists MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING add constraint FKosyih1e60ld4bp8f7hege9xar foreign key (id) references MY_SECOND_ENTITY
Hibernate: insert into MY_FIRST_ENTITY (title,id) values (?,?)
Hibernate: with id_cte (id) as materialized (select mse1_0.id from MY_SECOND_ENTITY mse1_0 left join MY_SECOND_ENTITY_MAPPING mse1_1 on mse1_0.id=mse1_1.id),update_cte_MY_SECOND_ENTITY (id) as (update MY_SECOND_ENTITY set title=null where id in (select id.id from id_cte id) returning id) select count(*) from id_cte id
Hibernate: insert into MY_FIRST_ENTITY (title,id) values (?,?)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and same java code does not generate that unique index exception.

In theory if I disable auto commit it should have worked for h2 but it did not, I tried AUTOCOMMIT=OFF on jdbc url but still same exception. I left the config in properties.

Comment: Based on your answer I did some more debugging. I thinks it's actually going to `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement` (but it has basically the same Javadoc). I'm not sure if the Javadoc says that if will always commit if it is a DDL statement (regardless of autocommit on/off). For me this is quite unexpected behaviour that the transaction can be committed unknowingly.

I also verified that the problem does not happen on HSQLDB and HANA DB.

Comment: The H2 documentation (http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_table) states, that `TRANSACTIONAL` modifier can be given for creating temporary tables to avoid committing!

Comment: also you can use hbm2ddl create-drop, no need to write those create tables.